# JSP não exibe imagens nem encontra CSS e Javascript

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Boa noite,

Estou com um problema estranho, estou tentando exibir imagens, mapear CSS e JS no jsp e não esta funcionando, simplesmente não encontra, o mais estranho é que estou usando a tag c:url da "jstl/core" tb tentei usar ${pageContext.request.contextPath} e não funcionou.

estou usando Servlet simples sem nenhum framework.

[image: estrutura]

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>clientes atuantes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/layout.css"/>">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.0.js" />"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <main>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default espacamentoExterno5">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/ativo.gif"/>" /> ativo</p>
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/congelado.gif"/>" /> congelado</p>
                        <p><img src="<c:url value="/img/cancelado.gif"/>" /> cancelado</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
```

alguém sabe o q pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Poderia editar sua pergunta com a estrutura de diretórios da sua aplicação? Pode ser que você esteja colocando os arquivos no lugar errado.

Comment: Parece que você não está escapando as aspas. Tente `<img src="<c:url value=\""/img/designado1.gif\""/>"/>`

Comment: coloquei a estrutura

Comment: Tente colocar `../` sobe um nível na pasta. Um exemplo: <img src="<c:url value="../img/ativo.gif"/>" />

Comment: Nenhuma das suas opções resolveu, continuou mesma

Comment: @Bandoleiro tem erro no console? f12-> console. Tenta tirar também o <c:url value= não precisa. Outra ideia, tenta colocar <img src="../../img/ativo.gif"/>" />

Comment: tb não funcionou

Comment: galera, não faço mas a menor ideia do q posso fazer pra resolver isso